# A distinção visual entre tags obrigatórias e comuns no meta é sutil demais

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, layout, meta, meta-tags

Comparem o visual das tags obrigatórias aqui e no metão:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha opinião, a distinção aqui é sutil demais. As obrigatórias têm um fundo em `#f0f0f0`, enquanto as comuns são ligeiramente mais escuras, em `#e7e7e7`. É possível enfatizar visualmente a distinção entre os tipos de tag?

Comment: O que leva a outra questão mais ampla. Porque tem tantas diferenças se estamos usando o mesmo tema do SO original? Ou não estamos? E porque é diferente? Se fosse para diferenciar alguma coisa, o ícone seria a primeira diferença. Relacionado: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/22/mudar-favicon-para-torna-lo-um-pouco-distinto-do-usado-no-stackoverflow-em-ingle

Comment: Não estamos usando o mesmo tema, o nosso tem várias diferenças. Pode ser que estejamos testando o futuro tema do SO :-). Particularmente, acho o nosso melhor, apesar dos problemas.

Comment: Foi mais uma provocação :) Algumas coisas são melhores neste, outras nem tanto. Não gosto por exemplo do estilo do *syntax highlight*. Talvez até por estar acostumado com o original.